# Arrow function passing a variable within a prop within a .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass a variable to a prop function in React that is all within a .map function.

I am getting an Invalid Left-Hand Side in arrow function parameters error.

```
<div style={ style.navContainer }>
    {navItems.map((item, i) => <div key={ i } onClick={ (item.name) => this.props.onClickGoTo(name) } style={ style.navItem }>
                <img style={ style.icon } src={ item.src } />
                { item.name }</div>)}
</div>
```

Comment: I think you don't need to declare (item.name), you can access to it directly using this.props.onClickGoTo(item.name) withouth the declaration before the "=> "

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Thank you man. It is `() => this.props.onClickGoTo(item.name)` Hmmmm, interesting. Brilliant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost. It should be:

```
onClick={ () => this.props.onClickGoTo(item.name) }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Jeff. I'll be sure to give you a harder one next time :P